# how to pass two values in one variable through associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, associative-array

I have a UberGallery.php from the [UberGallery](http://www.ubergallery.net/) which is I am using.

For each image popup there is image name(e.g 4488826 6f061c99ec b d) displayed at the bottom of image which is taking from UberGallery.php

```
  // Loop through array and add additional info
            foreach ($dirArray as $key => $image) {
                // Get files relative path
                $relativePath = $this->_rImgDir . '/' . $key;

                $galleryArray['images'][htmlentities(pathinfo($image['real_path'], PATHINFO_BASENAME))] = array(
                    'file_title'   => str_replace('_', ' ', pathinfo($image['real_path'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)),
                    'file_path'    => htmlentities($relativePath),
                    'thumb_path'   => $this->_createThumbnail($image['real_path'])
                );
            }
```

**file_title**  from above code is affecting that title to be changed. Images are displayed like below in defaultGallery.php

```
 <?php if (!empty($images) && $stats['total_images'] > 0): ?>

        <ul id="galleryList" class="clearfix">

            <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo html_entity_decode($image['file_path']); ?>" title="<?php echo $image['file_title']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $relText; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['file_title']; ?>"/></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>

    <?php else: ?>

        <p>No images found.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Now I want to show the image name(4488826 6f061c99ec b d) and email address(aaa@gmail.com) both at bottom of the image for each image popup.

if I changed in above **file_title's** `str_replace` function to get email address from csv file then nothing gets appeared.
`gallery.csv` is having two field like `4488826 6f061c99ec b d aaa@gmail.com`. These two values I want to pass to file_title so that they gets appear in image popup.

```
$file_handle = fopen("gallery.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

$lines_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);

            // Loop through array and add additional info
            foreach ($dirArray as $key => $image) {
                // Get files relative path
                $relativePath = $this->_rImgDir . '/' . $key;

                $galleryArray['images'][htmlentities(pathinfo($image['real_path'], PATHINFO_BASENAME))] = array(
                    'file_title'   => str_replace('_', $lines_of_text[1], pathinfo($image['real_path'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)),
                    'file_path'    => htmlentities($relativePath),
                    'thumb_path'   => $this->_createThumbnail($image['real_path'])
                );
            }
```

How should I pass name and email to above **file_title** to get required result?
Or is there any other way to do this?

Please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this one like

```
 $galleryArray['images'][htmlentities(pathinfo($image['real_path'], PATHINFO_BASENAME))] = array(
                'file_title'   => ' ',
                'file_path'    => htmlentities($relativePath),
                'thumb_path'   => $this->_createThumbnail($image['real_path'])
            );
```

Comment: if we kept file_title blank then nothing is appearing. I want to show two fields as i mentioned in question.

Comment: @ priya786: any idea how should i do that?

Comment: you want name and email both in place of title

Comment: yaah, i want to change that title which is at the bottom of **image popup** (please check demo of the link which i have provided) with the image name and email. I am trying to fetch that both from csv file and show there. But not able to do that.

Comment: @ priya786: your answer is not enough what OP is asking for.